# How move plan and sattelite button on google map API

Tags: google-maps

I notice the buttons "plan" and "sattelite" moved from the bottom left corner to the top, but I already use the top left corner to display input, button, data, etc. How can I move them where they were before and not have to remake all my css ?

Comment: What does your code look like?  Have you looked at [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#ControlPositioning)?

Comment: Thank you for this link, apparently google map api changed since yesterday

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your comment. The Google Maps Javascript API v3 changes all the time.  Are you using that?  Are you using an [embedded map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed)? You might help us answer your question if you provided some more information.

Comment: I use google javascript API, but I doesn't know many things about it, I just display a map and some marker, I said that was with google map API thinked it was obvious that was not an embedded map, but you already answer my question with your link, thank you for your help.

Comment: It wasn't obvious to me that you used the Google Maps Javascript API v3 from the question (or I wouldn't have asked).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mapTypeControlOptions    google.maps.ControlPositiion

```
var mapOptions = {
 .....
mapTypeControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
},
```